# Is the product space $(0,1]^\kappa$ Lindelöf?

Tags: general-topology

Topological space is called *Lindelöf* if every of its open covers has a countable subcover. Let $(0,1]$ a subspace of the real line. It is obviously not compact, but still it is a least Lindelöf. What about its $\kappa$ product $(0,1]^\kappa$ for arbitrary uncountable cardinal $\kappa$, is it also Lindelöf? It probably will not be the case, yet I could not manage to find a counterexample.

Comment: A topological space is called Lindelöf if every of its open covers has a $\color{red}{\text{countable}}$ subcover.

Comment: @user170039, how did you produce red colour? :)

Comment: @TomekKania: Use the code `$\color{red}{\text{some text}}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(0,1]^\kappa$ is not Lindelöf for any uncountable $\kappa$. This follows from the fact that the following are equivalent for any Hausdorff space $X$:

- $X$ is compact;
- $X^\kappa$ is Lindelöf for every cardinal $\kappa$;
- $X^{\omega_1}$ is Lindelöf.

It’s easy to see that each statement implies the next, so we need only prove that the last implies the first. This takes some work; you can find an argument in [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/9651).